# Jquery multi select box

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<select multiple="multiple" class="listBox" name="drop1" id="toList">
    <option value="1">John Doe (1)</option>
    <option value="2">John Doe (2)</option>
    <option value="3">John Doe (3)</option>
    <option value="4">John Doe (4)</option>
    <option value="5">John Doe (5)</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to be able to grab every single option in this toList and build out a delimited list that I will then post to another page.

What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I thought of originally doing:

```
$(#toList).each(function () {
     var myList = myList + $(this).val();
    });

$.post('somepage.asp', userList: myList);
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want every option, or every selected option?

Comment: That looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan every option.  They build a list into this box, from another box.  So everything in this box I assume they want the message sent to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work nicely:

```
var myList = []
$("#toList > option").each(function () {
  myList.push($(this).val());
});

$.post('somepage.asp', userList: myList.join(","));
```

Or if you only want the selected values:

```
var myList = []
$("#toList > option:selected").each(function () {
  myList.push($(this).val());
});

$.post('somepage.asp', userList: myList.join(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want every selected value, you can just use `.val()` on the `select` as javascript will automatically provide you with a comma delimited list of the selected values:

```
$.post('somepage.asp', userList: $("#toList").val());
```

If you want every value of the select then push to an array:

```
var values = [];
$("option", this).each(function() {
    values.push($(this).val());
});
$.post('somepage.asp', userList: values.join(','));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, currently I am alerting out the values and it cuts it off.  Is there a limit in how big the array can be, sometimes I could be passing upwards of 5,000 numbers into this array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try jQuery's `map()` method.

```
var myList = $('#toList option').map(function(){ return this.value; });
alert(myList.toArray().join(','));​
```

`map()` passes each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.

Reference - http://api.jquery.com/map/

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Nr4g9/